# h4 HTML tag affecting div alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm testing out some web layout, and I've come across a curious problem.

When I use an h4 tag in the top of a div, it "pushes" the div downwards.

It's easily fixed by adding a padding (or other things) to the div element, but I would like to know why this happens...

Can anyone tell me? Code is below:

**CSS:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* stjerne angir alle elementer, */

/* vi ønsker å putte padding og border inni alle bokser. */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#innpakning {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}
#overskrift {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#horisontalmeny ul {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#horisontalmeny ul li {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
}
#horisontalmeny ul li a:link {
  display: block;
}
#vertikalmeny {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#vertikalmeny ul {} #vertikalmeny ul li {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: block;
}
#hovedinnhold {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="innpakning">
  <div id="overskrift">
    <h1> Velkommen </h1>

  </div>
  <!-- /overskrift -->
  <div id="horisontalmeny">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /horisontalmeny -->
  <div id="vertikalmeny">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lenke 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- vertikalmeny -->
  <div id="hovedinnhold">
    <h4> Overskrift 1 </h4>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at ligula et lorem ornare egestas. In vestibulum, massa sed aliquet pharetra, magna arcu luctus risus, nec auctor dui felis ac tellus. Integer vitae odio in turpis commodo finibus sit
      amet ornare enim. Duis ut turpis ultricies, placerat quam nec, ultricies augue. Praesent et dui dolor. Fusce vitae ex scelerisque, suscipit lorem eu, faucibus lorem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
      mus. Ut hendrerit nisl et ultricies luctus.</p>
    <h4> Overskrift 2 </h4>

    <p>Integer tempor accumsan tempus. Fusce massa libero, suscipit non elementum vitae, consequat sit amet justo. Vestibulum sagittis consectetur lectus dapibus interdum. Nulla ac ante tempus, mollis felis vitae, pulvinar massa. Integer sed enim sit amet
      nulla venenatis feugiat. Nulla facilisi. Fusce in mattis quam, sit amet aliquet mi. Aenean accumsan ipsum et pellentesque fringilla. Nunc bibendum fringilla sodales. Etiam pellentesque ultricies velit id consequat. Ut sollicitudin sagittis tellus,
      vitae gravida erat faucibus sit amet.</p>
    <h4> Overskrift 3 </h4>

    <p>Nulla ultricies at felis ac porttitor. Nullam accumsan consectetur dui, eget suscipit nunc accumsan scelerisque. Sed neque velit, bibendum ut ante ac, fringilla placerat lacus. Proin venenatis ullamcorper est quis scelerisque. Sed porttitor erat lectus.
      Pellentesque viverra velit sit amet leo vestibulum lacinia. Duis facilisis elit at rutrum interdum. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent fermentum metus massa, et mattis nunc vestibulum id. Quisque congue mauris in eros convallis, non consequat magna pulvinar.
      Curabitur nec mauris quis diam imperdiet venenatis. Curabitur ullamcorper felis et ex consectetur vehicula eget nec velit.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- hovedinnhold -->
</div>
<!-- /innpakning -->
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo662qhg/) LINK

Comment: "When I use an tag in the top of a div" - what do you mean?

Comment: Do you meant that '<h4> Overskrift 1 </h4>' is slighter down than menu on left?

Comment: If I understand your question you will be looking for this, [**Margin Collapsing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). This will be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the h4 tag, it has dropped out of the question.

Comment: It's the top-margin of the <h4> element that pushing that section down.  By default, in my browser, that's set to 21px.

Comment: @LarsNersveen Check my answer. As your question is can anyone tell me why its doing it, I believe this answers it (100% sure this is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cause of margin collapsing.

As you stated already the ways to stop them are adding a border, padding and inline content or just get rid of margins all together.

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

[More about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `top-margin` from your first `<h4>`. This should resolve your problems.